# Code signing "libswiftAVFoundation.dylib" failed

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

my Xcode version 9.2 swift 4
Mac OS 10.13.4
[getting error while creating IPA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OGPXf.png)

Answer (score 0):

It requires a code signing identity and provisioning profile in XCode.

Answer (score 0):

If it helps anyone else, I was seeing a very similar problem when exporting an archive using xcodebuild that I fixed by updating the command line tools and ensuring that the path was correct (was getting messed up because of an Xcode beta installation).

More info: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/46431/xcode-appears-to-be-installed-but-xcodebuild-is-unusable

Answer (score 0):

verify in xcode General signing Certificate if the profile is Distribution and not Developer. Case Developer unchecked automatically manage signing and change manual provisioning profile (update certificate, case expired or revoked);

Archive (legacy profile) and Distributed